# Android custom layout with different number of childs in row

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview, android-adapter, android-adapterview

I have been developing android for a while and I have been facing many similar layouts to the one in screenshot (in both iOS and Android)

So what I would like to achieve is the different number of childs in each row.

Well, first I would like to ask is there a specific name for this layout type, it is not gridview although very close to it.

The structure seems like it can be populated with an adapter since all child buttons look alike

Any help, suggestion, solution or example library is much appreciated.

[image: Foursquare for Android, Resulting Layout]

**Taken from Foursquare for Android**

Comment: What's stopping you from using a normal ListView and calculating the number of rows based on how many children fit the width of the list?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a chance of more than two childs (as you said) therefore what i think is that you can't accommodate so many childs as they would not be visible unless the listview row is horizontally scrollable.......I think you can use gallery widget as an item of listview and then you can have different childs in each row... You can google about the gallery widget, instead of images add your custom layout as gallery item.